# Loading data in Grid based on Drop-down List Selection and submit button in Angular 4

Tags: angular, grid

I could achieve this in Angular JS but not sure how to do this in Angular 4?

I have a requirement where I have two dropdowns. Value of 2nd dropdown is dependent on the selection of values in first dropdown. I have achieved this.

Now I have search button after these two dropdowns. Once the user clicks on search button, respective data should get displayed in grid.

I tried, angular data grid, Kendo UI etc, but no luck.

[image]

I have attached screen shot for the same.

Note: Dropdown functionality is completed. The only pending thing is to populate data in grid. I could display grid directly with data but I need to do it based on the dropdown selection and after pressing on the search button.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks @halfer. Will keep in mind.